# Proving function statement true or false

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to determine if the following statement is true or false. Please can you help and tell me why it is the case.

If $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ are two arbitrary functions $f(n)=O(g(n))$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ is an increasing continuous bijective function, then $h(f(x))= O(h(g(x)))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

By definition, there exists $N\geq 0$ and $C > 0$ such that for all $n \geq N$ one has $f(n) \leq C\cdot g(n)$. This guarantees that for every such $n$
$$
 h(f(n)) \leq h(Cg(n))
$$
not more. The tricky part comes from the constant $C$, which does not allow to conclude. And indeed, take $f\colon n \mapsto 2n$, $g\colon n\mapsto n$; the premise holds, for any $C \geq 2$. But taking $h$ to be increasing really fast, say $h\colon x \mapsto e^x$, you would need $D> 0$ and $N^\prime$ such that, for all $n\geq N^\prime$
$$
 e^{2n} \leq D\cdot e^{n}
$$
or equivalently $\frac{e^{2n}}{e^n}=e^n$ is bounded. This is not true.